# how to show facebook window as pop-up in new ios sdk 3.2 and above ? What to do ? I just have .h files in new facebook sdk

Tags: ios

AS in iOS sdk 3.2 and above there is 2 things either facebook app is open or browser is open but i want it like pop up view as in old sdk ? So what ot do now ?

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to the "Feed Dialog". Learn more about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/).

Facebook have introduced `FBWebDialog` for displaying these "popups" you're referring to.